# regex validation in refind function in coldfusion

Tags: regex, coldfusion

I'm trying to validate the following rules:

1. string must needs to be length of 5 characters.
2. first 2 characters needs to be "US" or "CA"
3. then any 3 characters that's printable

Here is the code. Please let me know if this is okay.

```
<cfset string="US_tx">
<cfset indexofoccurrence="REFind("\b(US|CA)[[:word:]]{3}$"," string)="">
<cfdump var="#IndexOfOccurrence#">
```

Comment: Dunno why the close flag? It's a reasonable question.

Comment: Well the easiest way to answer your own question is: *does it work*? What is it that lead you to be asking the question?

Comment: If you want `any 3 characters that's printable` you should use `[:print:]` instead of `[:word:]`

Answer (score 1):

First things first... if you're going to post code, make sure it at least *compiles*, which this code does not.

Still, if one looks at the regex itself... it's close, but you're only anchoring the regex to the *end* of the string; if you want the entire string to match the regex, you need to anchor it to the beginning of the string too, ie:

```
^(US|CA)[[:word:]]{3}$
```

Comment: thank you Adam, This is working now for me. thanks a lot for correcting my regex :)